# Aura tag rename

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

I would like to suggest the rename of the "aura" tag to "aurajs". This is more appropriate as there are other frameworks or libraries with the name "aura" such as http://documentation.auraframework.org/

Answer (score 2):

To match other naming conventions for javascript libraries (or whatever you call them), I created a new tag [aura.js](/questions/tagged/aura.js), retagged all 10 questions with the old [aura](/questions/tagged/aura), and moved the wiki information for [aura](/questions/tagged/aura) over to the new [aura.js](/questions/tagged/aura.js).

The old [aura](/questions/tagged/aura) will be deleted in a regular cleanup as it has no questions right now. You may want to change this to a request to synonymize [aurajs](/questions/tagged/aurajs) with [aura.js](/questions/tagged/aura.js) since that tends to be the trend with other libraries.

When there are just a few questions, you can make those sorts of changes yourself -- no need to ask for help from the community (you have more rep on SO than I do, after all).